Moving to the man
Assalamualykum
I’ve got a very important question. I know a sitution where a woman and a man are talking together. This man lives in another city than the woman. In Islam it says that the woman is moving to her husband after marriage, but is it like obligatory? Even if the man lives in another city, can’t he like move to the woman’s city? He’s saying like if that wasn’t like a «rule» he could’ve moved to her. I think it’s very wrong to use that like an excuse. What is the right thing to do?
JazakhAllah Khair.
